# Export Flash parameters to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to pass parameters from Flash (as 3.0) to JavaScript. 
Tried all methods I found in via. Google, as:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback ("fonts", recieveFromJS);
```

Always one and the same problem; when I try to call the fonts () swfobject, JavaScript gives the error that the method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your javascript code does not have a syntax error somewhere, this usually happens because of jquery (or some other js bundle) is stepping on your code.  Try using a test page with just the javascript you need, removing all other  code and  header entries.  If it works, then add scripts and links back, one at a time, and you will find which code is breaking it.  If it does not work even in your test page, then you have a code/syntax/logic problem with the snippet of code you are working with.  If you still have a problem with a code snippet, post it here and I or someone will surely help debug it for you.